# Probability mass function and conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

If $p_X(k)$ and $p_{Y|X}(y|k)$ are given, how can we calculate $p_Y(y)$? We cannot assume that $p_Y(y)$ and $p_X(k)$ are independent.

I know that $p_X(k) \cdot p_{Y|X}(y|k) = p_{Y,X}(y,k)$ but how can I isolate $p_Y(y)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $p_X(k)$ and $p_{X|Y}(y|k)$? What probabilities (or densities) of *what* exactly are those? Of $X$ respectively $X|Y$? Of $k$?

Comment: X and Y are random variables. y and k are the values that you put into the probability mass functions.

Comment: Also there is a typo by you, $p_X(x) \cdot p_{Y|X}(y|x)=p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and not the way you wrote.

Comment: Thanks I corrected it

Comment: Just integrate the product w.r.t. $x$ to getthe answer. It is standard way to find marginal density from joint density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with discrete random variables, the way you find
$p_Y(y)$ is using summations:

$$p_Y(y) = \sum_k p_{Y,X}(y,k) = \sum_k p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid k)p_X(k)$$

where the sum on the right should be recognized as coming from
[*the law of total probability*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).  Note that
$p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid k)$ is the *conditional* probability of the event
$A = \{Y = y\}$ *given* that the event $B_k = \{X = k\}$ has occurred,
while $p_X(k) = P\{X = k\}$ is just $P(B_k)$. The law of total 
probability tells us that

$$P(A) = \sum_k P(A\mid B_k)P(B_k)$$

where the events $B_k$ are a (countable) partition of the sample space.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Use $$p_Y(y)=\int_x p_{Y,X}(y,x) dx = \int_x p_X(x) \cdot p_{Y|X}(y|x) dx$$

EDIT:

For discrete case, just replace integration by summation as pointed out by Dilip.

P.S: How come you knew that he meant discrete and not continuous random variable??

Comment: The _title_ of the question is "Probability mass function and conditional probabilities" and so I assumed that the OP meant to ask about discrete random variables.